# PHP & MYSQL selection

Tags: php, mysql

Ok folks. I have a Table categories with id, categoryname.

categories has: id=1 categoryname = batteries, id=2 categoryname = flashes, id=3 categoryname glasses.

The Second table is users. Users have id, user_eimal, my_choices. 
Every user has store into my_choices the category name that wants to appear.

So for example user George with user_email xxxxx@xxx.com has store in my_choices: batteries,glasses

Now i want to bring up records from table products where categoryname is the values that user george has stored into my_choices.

Products has id, p_title, categoryname

for example i want to:

```
 <?php

    $usenmail = $_SESSION['SESS_EMAYL_NAME'];

    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '$id'";
    $q2 = mysql_query($q1, $connectiondb) or die(mysql_error());
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2);

    $my_choices = $results['my_choices']; //That means $my_choices = batteries,glasses

    //Now i want to select fom my table poducts only the categories (batteries,glasses)that user has store.

$trt = mysql_query ("select * from products where categoryname = batteries,glasses");

while($apst = mysql_fetch_assoc($trt)) {  

echo '<div style="color: #000; float: left;">Productname: '.$['apst'].'</div>'; 
echo '<br>'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Normalise your tables.... don't use comma-separated lists in your products table but create a separate product_categories table, otherwise you'll cause yourself no end of grief in the future

Comment: please can you give me an adivise how i can do this?

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them, and not just a list of requirements. We're here to help, not do your job for you, nor are we coders for hire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a join table so you can have a many-to-many relationship. Your current structure is better suited to each user only having ONE choice.

What you want are three tables:

- Users (userID, user_name, user_email)
- Categories (categoryID, category_name)
- Users_Categories (userID, categoryID)

So to use your example, your three tables would look like this (if anyone knows a better way to demonstrate SQL tables on here, please let me know):

**Users**

- userID: 1 | user_name: George | user_email: george@example.com

**Categories**

- categoryID: 1 | category_name: batteries
- categoryID: 2 | category_name= flashes
- categoryID: 3 | category_nameglasses.

**Users_Categories**

- userID: 1 | categoryID: 1
- userID: 1 | categoryID: 3

You would then use a select statement with a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) clause to get George and his categories:

```
SELECT 
    user_name,
    category_name
FROM
    Users
    LEFT JOIN Users_Categories USING (userID)
    LEFT JOIN Categories USING (categoryID)
WHERE
    userID = 1
```

This would return two rows in the result:

1. George, Batteries
2. George, Glasses

Depending on what you want to do with that data, it may be better to also select the userID.

If you want a query that will only return one row with all of the information, it gets a little trickier. You have to use the [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) functionality. That would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT (category_name ',')
FROM
    Users
    LEFT JOIN Users_Categories USING (userID)
    LEFT JOIN Categories USING (categoryID)
GROUP BY
    userID
WHERE
    userID = 1
```

For your final question about products, you would follow the same logic with more joins. Your Products table wants to have a productID, product_name, and categoryID.

Comment: A very good suggestion, this would enable easy searches for products. Also it would not limit the amount of categories a product could have. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$trt = mysql_query ("select * from products where categoryname = 'batteries' OR categoryname = 'glasses'");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case use select statement as,

```
select * from products where categoryname in ( 'batteries','glasses');
```

ie,

```
//add quotes to category names (if ids you dont neeed these 2 lines)
$cats=explode(',',$my_choices);
$strcats = "'" . join("', '", $cats) . "'"; 

$trt = mysql_query ("select * from products where categoryname in ($strcats));
```

My suggestion to use category ids instead of category names.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct example in the OPs case, because `categoryname` is comma separated set of multiple values. It would work if it were a single value field.

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function

```
$array = explode(','$my_choices);
```

now array[0] and array[1] have the 2 values. then use

```
$result = mysql_query ("select * from products where categoryname = '".$array[0]."' OR categoryname = '".$array[1]."'");
```

Comment: mysql query $result must be dynamic coz i dont know "or" how many values has.. Am i correct?

Comment: I am not sure if i get your question. If you are trying to tell that you dont know the number of OR statements to be added you can write a loop like:

`$i=0;
while(isset($array[i]))`

Comment: soory about the previous one, it was incomplete

I am not sure if i get your question. If you are trying to tell that you dont know the number of OR statements to be added you can write a loop like:

`$i=0;
while(isset($array[i]))
$data = $data." OR ".$array[$i]; 
`

then include it in your sql query

Comment: yes demonslyer you are correct. I dont know the number of "OR". i will try your code and let you know mate.